# sum score in ajax not working with laravel5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have `score` field in table of infractions. And I have many checkboxes. When I checked the chechboxes, The total of scores are collected with ajax.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            @foreach($infractions as $infraction)
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ $infraction->title }}</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-score="{{ $infraction->score }}" onClick="updateTotal();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">Total:
        <span id="total">

        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Score]

Ajax

```
function scorePlus (id)
{
    var total = id + id;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            @foreach($infractions as $infraction)
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ $infraction->title }}</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-score="{{ $infraction->score }})" onClick="updateTotal();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">Total:
        <span id="total">0</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function updateTotal() {
        var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
        var score = 0;

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(checked, function(el, i){
            score += parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-score'));
        });

        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = score;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Now go to https://www.laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-display-json-in-blade-laravel site. And aswered

Comment: Thanks for answer. I updated `<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-score="{{ $infraction->score }}" onClick="updateTotal();">` 
but it is not working